# Where to find topics and problems to write about?

Tags: publications, research-undergraduate, research-topic

I am an undergraduate student in ***English Language Translation***. I would like to do research and write papers about topics or problems that are available in this field of study.

I googled about possible places where I might be able to find topics or titles to write about (like websites of universities, academies or int'l schools) but I couldn't find any.

Is there any up-to-date database or website that provides such lists?

Comment: The best place to start would be reading some recent papers in the field. That way you can find out what the current hot topics are.

Comment: The literature here is vast. Perhaps you could start with something recent, published just this month: [Jessica Moore: The Art of Translation](https://canadianart.ca/essays/the-art-of-translation/).

Comment: I'm surprised your professor(s) can't help you with that. Especially if you are in a dedicated program.

Comment: Do you have an advisor?